# AppArmor audit log location

Tags: ubuntu, audit, apparmor

Trying to debug with apparmor rules from audit logs.
In my workstation(Ubuntu 20), using `dmesg` gets audit DENIED/ALLOWED logs.

```
 audit: type=1400 audit(1645465219.195:1219484): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="unlink" profile="xxx"
```

But where is theses logs store?
In `/var/log/audit/audit.log` didn't have these detail logs.
Need to know these logs location for `aa-logprof` use.

Answer (score 0):

You can find them stored under:
/var/log/syslog